# MySQL Optimising order by primary key on large table with limit

Tags: mysql, optimization

Sorry for a cryptic title... My issue:

I have a mysql query which in the most simplified form would looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE _SOME\_CONDITIONS_
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Without the `LIMIT` clause, the query would return around 50,000 rows, however I am ever only interested in the first 50 rows. Now I realise that because I add `ORDER BY` bit MySQL has to create a temporary table and load all results in it, then order the 50,000 results and only then it can return the first 50 results.

When I compare performance of this query versus query without `ORDER BY` I get a staggering difference of 1.8 seconds vs 0.02 seconds.

Given that `id` is auto incrementing primary key I thought that there should be an elegant work around for my problem. Is there any?

Comment: What are your indexes and your WHERE clause like?
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html for advice on having MySQL use indexes to resolve your ORDER BY without a temporary table, though it may or may not be possible for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are the *SOME_CONDITIONS* such that you could give the query an ID range? At the very least, you could limit the number of rows being added into the temporary table before the sort.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE _SOME\_CONDITIONS_
AND id BETWEEN 1 AND 50;
```

Alternatively maybe a nested query to give the min and max IDs if the *SOME_CONDITIONS* prevent you from making this sort of assumption about the range of IDs in your result.

If the performance is really that important, I would de-normalize the data by creating another table or cache of the first 50 results and keeping it updated separately.